# Streaming Django template with large generator in context

Tags: django, streaming, gunicorn

I want to render large log files in a Django template.

To do so, the template renders individual lines provided by a generator that streams the log file from disk.

The template rendering just stops after some time though and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

My Django app is running with gunicorn & nginx (config below).

I can see that the relevant response headers are set, so I don't know why the logs stop rendering ~30-40 seconds in:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.4
Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 12:53:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Relevant part of the template:

```
<div class="log-body">
{% for line in log %}
  {{ line }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The rendering function in `views.py`

```
def render_log(request):
    log = read_log_file_gen("some_path.log")

    if not log:
        log = ["No logs found"]

    template = loader.get_template('show_log.html')
    context = {
        'log': log,
    }

    return StreamingHttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def read_log_file_gen(path):
    _256KB = 256 * 1024
    try:
        with open(path) as f:
            while True:
                lines = f.readlines(_256KB)
                if not lines:
                    break
                yield "".join(lines)
    except IOError:
        return None
```

The app runs through docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -k gevent
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /mnt/data:/mnt/data
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env.prod
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this, but in the process realised that trying to display large log files in the browser is a bad idea, as some of them are really really big.

In case anyone is trying to do this (with slightly less large files), note that templates are fundamentally rendered synchronously, so the above approach doesn't really work.

Instead, you can load a parent template, and in there make an AJAX call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'myapp:logs' log.id %}",
            dataType: "text/plain",
            success: function (logText) {
                $("#logText").replaceWith(logText)
            }
        });
</script>
```

The function at url `myapp:logs` can then use the `StreamingHttpResponse`:

```
from django.template import loader


def log(request, log_id):
    log_gen = read_log_file_gen(f"{log_id}.log")
    template = loader.get_template('mytemplates/log.html')
    return StreamingHttpResponse(log_render_gen(template, log_gen))


def log_render_gen(template, log_gen):
    for log in log_gen:
        yield template.render({'log_line': log})


def read_log_file_gen(path):
    _256KB = 256 * 1024
    try:
        with open(path) as f:
            while True:
                lines = f.readlines(_256KB)
                if not lines:
                    break
                yield "".join(lines)
    except IOError:
        return None
```

The asynchronous result from rendering `log.html` is placed inside a `<pre>`, so I just render the log text as-is:

```
{{ log_line }}
```